# OS X chat app with resizable bubbles

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, chat

I'm building chat application for Mac OS, similar to iMessage. I wonder, how can I implement resizable text views in bubbles. I mean, when I resize chat window bubbles with text will resize to. Any ideas, links will be very useful. Thank you for help)

Comment: Hi based on the discussion at JSQMessageViewController, I think by adding little more tricks you can have the iMessage like UI working on macOS. Please check this thread: https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/issues/1929 

and this: http://chameleonproject.org/

Answer (score 1):

For text resizing, you use auto layout. If you have an NSScrollView containing `MYBubbleView`s containing `NSTextView`s, you can add `NSLayoutConstraint`s using the `leftAnchor` and `rightAnchor` properties of the scroll view's content view and those of the bubble view, and add constraints between all edges of the text view and bubble view. Then pin the bubble views to the top/prev view.

Also make sure you set the `NSTextView` to wrap. The width of the intrinsic size of the text view will be set so that it fills the width and the intrinsic height will be set to fit the whole text.

*I previously thought it was about drawing the bubbles, so I first gave this answer:*

If you look at Messages.app, you'll see that they're not circular bubbles. They are basically composed of several shapes overlaid on each other. A rectangle with rounded corners, plus a bezier path of the tip.

So you should be able to take a NSTextView for the text, make it a subview of a custom view that draws a rounded rectangle and the tip in its drawRect method, and then use auto layout constraints to make your bubble view resize with the text view and the text view to the window width.

You could probably also have the bubble view host a CALayer with fill and rounded corners, plus one with an image for the tip (or aCAShapeLayer for the tip), but drawRect is the easier approach.

Comment: bubbles itself not a big problem, the real problem is text resizing. When i resize window, text in bubbles should resize too